# Ksoap2 getPropertySafely return anyType{}

Tags: android, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I use ksoap2 to communicate with webservice. but when websrvice give response like follow, ksoap2 's method getPropertySafely will return "anyType{}", My expect is return ""
here is the xml response:

```
<ns2:value/>
```

java code:

```
value = sObject.getPropertySafely("value", "").toString();
```

Any advice will help, thanks

Comment: Same problem. Did you ever resolve this? Please don't tell me I have to write a parser to fill my complex classes.

Answer (score 2):

I've just had the same problem and found [this](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/issues/detail?id=50) bug. The patch submitted to solve the bug adds methods to get primitive properties, which solves the problem. E.g.:

```
value = sObject.getPrimitiveProperty("value").toString();
```

There are xSafely and xAsString variants too.